# Search function in lisp

Tags: search, lisp, common-lisp

How can i retrieve a list of items (string) which contain a specific word from another list. Here is an Example :

```
(setq l '("word1_jj" "word2_mm" "word3_jj" "word4_kk"))
```

I wanna extract all string in which figure "_jj.

Comment: One possible way is to use filter where a predicate matches a substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make `ends-with-p` that takes the word and an ending. To do that you find out how many characters there is in the two strings and use `subseq` to make a string consisting of the last letters of the word. You can use `equal` to check it with the supplied argument it should match.

When you have that you can do this:

```lisp
(remove-if-not (lambda (x) (ends-with-p x "_jj")) 
               '("word1_jj" "word2_mm" "word3_jj" "word4_kk"))

; ==> ("word1_jj" "word3_jj")
```

Alternatively you could make a `make-end-predicate` that returns a `lambda` that takes a word:

```lisp
(remove-if-not (make-end-predicate "_jj") 
               '("word1_jj" "word2_mm" "word3_jj" "word4_kk"))

; ==> ("word1_jj" "word3_jj")
```